# unix shell script to print the words and no.of. words that starts with a vowel

Tags: shell, unix

To Write a shell script that accepts the name of a text file and finds the number of sentences, number of words, and number of words that start with a vowel.
I had done trying with the below code. every time i try it shows the error

```
**enter code here
echo"Enter File Name:"
read file
lc=$(wc --lines $file)
wc=$(wc --words $file)
vow=$(grep -o -i" [^AEIOUaeiou]" | wc --words $file)
echo "Lines" $lc
echo "Words" $wc
echo "Vowels Words" $vow**
```

Comment: What error does it show?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
echo "Enter File Name:"
read file
lc=$(cat "${file}"|wc -l)
wc=$(cat "${file}"|wc -w)
vow=$(cat "${file}"|grep -o " [AEIOUaeiou][^ ]\+ " |wc -l)
echo "Lines: $lc"
echo "Words: $wc"
echo "Vowels Words: $vow"
```